# Unable to run open jar file

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I have taken the standard wordcount program
below is the standard example code

```
package myorg.org;
        import java.io.IOException;
        import java.util.*;

        import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
        import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
        import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
        import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.*;
        import org.apache.hadoop.util.*;

        public class WordCount {

            public static class Map extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
              private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
              private Text word = new Text();

              public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
                String line = value.toString();
                StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);
                while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
                  word.set(tokenizer.nextToken());
                  output.collect(word, one);
                }
              }
            }

            public static class Reduce extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {
              public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<IntWritable> values, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
                int sum = 0;
                while (values.hasNext()) {
                  sum += values.next().get();
                }
                output.collect(key, new IntWritable(sum));
              }
            }

            public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
              JobConf conf = new JobConf(WordCount.class);
              conf.setJobName("wordcount");

              conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
              conf.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

              conf.setMapperClass(Map.class);
              conf.setCombinerClass(Reduce.class);
              conf.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);

              conf.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);
              conf.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);

              FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path(args[0]));
              FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(args[1]));

              JobClient.runJob(conf);
            }
        }
```

I created a java project in eclipse and added `hadoop-common-2.0.0-cdh4.3.0.jar` and `hadoop-core-2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.3.0` jar as we are using Hadoop , it compiled successfully and I created jar file and copied that jar file into edge server, then i created 2 sample input files and i run the hadoop jar command , its saying `unable to open jar file` 
Below is the command i used for opening jar files

```
hadoop jar /home/a491882/Map-Reduce/WordCount.jar /home/a491882/Map-Reduce/input /home/a491882/Map-Reduce/output
```

I have the jar file present in that location and input files too, but unabele to find why this error is coming, in our hadoop cluster , we are using the hadoop-common-2.0.0-cdh4.3.0.jar and hadoop-core-2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.3.0 jar files

Please suggest what could be the problem.

Comment: Please clean your question up. If you want people to spend the time answering you, take a few extra minutes to write a sensible question.

Comment: Does the execution result in a stacktrace? What is the actual output produced?

Comment: When I just run the hadoop jar command from hadoop server , its giving error "unable to open jar file " which i created from eclipse .

Comment: looks like an easy java problem - it could not find a jar file, or it can not be decompressed ...

Comment: I found the error, when I copy into hadoop server and run the hadoop jar command , its working fine, as i got information from cloudera community , hadoop jar in HDFS will work only if using oozie .